# Wheatstone Bridge integrated circuit chip

Tags: sensor

Is there anything like a wheatstone bridge IC in various resistances with pins
to hookup the fourth resistance , and other connections ?

Comment: What's the point? It's resistors and a diff amp. It's like asking for an opamp where the resistors are built in.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy resistor networks that are matched to each other, such as [these](http://www.vishaypg.com/docs/63109/vfcd1505.pdf):

[image]

.. which could form half a bridge. The temperature coefficient typically tracks to within +/-0.1ppm/°C, which is pretty good. They're fairly expensive (but, 'compared to what?', one might ask).

If you just need crude 0.1% or 1% tolerance on the resistors and commensurate tempco, tempco tracking and stability, it's a lot cheaper and easier to just buy 3 thin-film or thick film resistors and wire them up.

Comment: ok thanks - did not know about the matched resistors